# Find All Elements in an Array which appears more than N/K times, N is Array Size and k is a Number

Tags: java, algorithm

Every where best algorithm given is this

1) Create a temporary array of size (k-1) to store elements and their counts (The output elements are going to be among these k-1 elements). Following is structure of temporary array elements.

2) Traverse through the input array and update temp[] (add/remove an element or increase/decrease count) for every traversed element. The array temp[] stores potential (k-1) candidates at every step. This step takes O(nk) time.

3) Iterate through final (k-1) potential candidates (stored in temp[]). or every element, check if it actually has count more than n/k. This step takes O(nk) time.

Resources i referred are :-

1) http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-of-of-size-n-finds-all-the-elements-that-appear-more-than-nk-times/

2) http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/find-all-elements-in-an-array-which-appears-more-than-nk-times-n-is-array-size-and-k-is-a-number/

**To me better algorithm looks like below which is O(n) **

1)Start iterating through array.

2)For each element check if element exist in hash map . If yes increase counter otherwise add it with counter 1

3)Also after addition of each element check whether count is greater than n/k times. If yes print

Here memory complexity will be O(N) which is bad than O(K-1) but time complexity is much better here which is O(n) compared to O(nk) in previuos algo.

so is n't second algo better considering time complexity and simplicity/readability or answer is  `Depends on` kind depending upon where we want to compromise i.e. either on
time or memory ?

Comment: Hashmap lookup takes `O(n)` (or, in convoluted implementations, `O(log n)`) in the worst case, where all elements hash to the same value. Also, not every object is necessarily hashable.

Comment: @Rhymoid A single `HashMap` lookup takes *O(1)*.

Comment: @Andreas That's in expectation; worst case, Rhymoid is right. If the objects can be ordered and we want worst case guarantees, a tree implementation is preferable.

Comment: *"isn't second algo better?"* That depends on whether memory is at a premium. Which depends on the value of `N` vs `K`.

Comment: @G.Bach Worst case is that all *distinct* values have same hash code, so `HashMap` will perform badly. Given that input are integers, that's definitely *not* the case here.

Comment: @Andreas Who says input are integers?

Comment: @G.Bach Sorry, I was looking at the example in the linked article.